# Can a registered class for injection be instantiated without a reference in a constructor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm injecting an object within `ConfigureServices()`, and I was hoping to have the object instantiated without a reference within a constructor. Is there any way to do this?

For example, I've got a service call like so:

```cs
services.CreateObjectBus<RecordingChunk>(p =>
    p.Configure(Configuration["AzureServiceBus:ConnectionString"], Queues.Editor,
        ObjectBus.BusType.Sender));
```

I'd like this to operate essentially like a background worker. I have a feeling this needs to be in a standalone project or in a random constructor call, although that would be less than ideal. Is there any way for me to do this?

#### Edit

To clarify, I'm injecting the object as shown above which calls the following to register it with DI.

```cs
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IObjectBus<T>, ObjectBus<T>>();
```

I'd like to have this object exist in the background, rather than requesting it in the constructor like so:

```cs
public EditorRepository(IObjectBus<Vocalia.ServiceBus.Types.Podcast> podcastBus)
{
    //podcastBus object isn't interacted with, but it needs to be instantiated.
}
```

I don't need to interact with this object per say, it just needs to exist in order for database and service bus connections to establish.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? I'm not understanding the "reference within a constructor" bit.

Comment: I've updated the question, although I feel like this should be moved to a separate project entirely as a WebJob or similar.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like a singleton?

Comment: It's essentially a background task, I'll implement it as a WebJob instead since it seems the better way to go about it

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to manually drive the dependency injection. You can do it. Just inject `IServiceProvider` in your constructor and store it.
Then, when you need it, just create a scope and then resolve the services as per your needs:

```
using (var serviceScope = m_ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var service = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyService>());
    ...
}
```

**Update**
Keep in mind that specifying what you need in the constructor is indeed the right way as you are clearly identifying what things you need to mock while testing.

This approach might be used in certain particular (and extreme) scenarious, but should be avoided as you are hiding the true dependencies.

Comment: Not exactly, but thanks for the reply. I've updated the question with clarification.

Comment: We shouldn't inject `IServiceProvider` into classes. That's the service locator antipattern. It means that in order to unit test the class you would have to inject either a real or mocked `IServiceProvider` which is configured to return a mock of `IMyService`.

Comment: You are right, it is antipattern and the user must be aware of what they are doing. As I am not aware of the context, i tried to answer to the precise question, even though it might not be the suitable solution to the real problem. Thank you for pointing out. I have updated the asnwer.